# gdb breakpoint won't set

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug C++ code using gdb. Particularly, I want to check if a certain variable (viscosities[j]) is not NAN and within certain bounds (eta_min and eta_max). I'm doing it using the following code:

```
if (!crash)
    {
        if (viscosities[j]>=eta_min && viscosities[j]<=eta_max)
            {}
        else
            {
                std::cout<<"viscosities[j]: "<<viscosities[j]<<"  ";
                crash = true;
            }
    }
```

(I need the variable crash because the code part of a loop, it's initialized to 0 before the loop starts).

In gdb, I'm trying to set the breakpoint using the following command:

```
break nz.cc:238
```

(line 238 is one with the cout statement) 
However, the breakpoint is instead set to line 246:

```
Breakpoint 3 at 0xaeeb09: file /home/lev/aspect/aspect/source/material_model/nz.cc, line 246. (2 locations)
```

and the compiler never stops at line 238. I verified the line number through vi and made sure to rebuild the executable. Can anyone please give me an idea of why this might be happening? Thanks in advance!

UPD: solved by disabling optimization during executable compilation

Comment: I would guess that you are trying to debug an optimised build - try building a debug version instead.

Comment: It it ever reached?

Comment: Was the code compiled with optimizations?

Comment: Have you tried printing viscosities[j], eta_min and eta_max before the if condition?

Comment: Indeed, I had it compiled with optimization. Thanks everyone for the help!